# GestureOverlayView causes strange TableRow blending

Tags: android, layout, gestures

Simple problem: 
With the XML layout shown below, I have some views wrapped in a GestureOverlayView. As shown below, my first row is blended with the second row, as-if the first row is transposed right on top of the second.

Now when I take the GestureOverlayView out of the code and leave everything else as-is, my table looks fine - the rows are separate and not on top of each other.

I'm wondering why the rows overlap like that with the gestureOverlayView present?

Screenshot showing the problem: http://img413.imageshack.us/img413/4994/overlayblending.png

Thank you

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout 
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/ll1"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >

    <android.gesture.GestureOverlayView 
      android:id="@+id/gesturePage01"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1.0">


        <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow01" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView 
                android:text="Connection info" 
                android:id="@+id/tvCon1" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#F0F0F0"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                />

        </TableRow>


        <TableRow android:id="@+id/TableRow02" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ScrollView 
            android:id="@+id/ScrollView01" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">

                <TextView  
                    android:id="@+id/tvMessages"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                    android:text=""
                    />

        </ScrollView>

    </TableRow>

</android.gesture.GestureOverlayView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went ahead and put my tableRow into a TableLayout and that fixed the problem.